# how can i use my stubbaseclass as a base for a new class for testing

Tags: c#

```
public class stubBaseTx : BaseTxFlowOperations
    {
        private MockRepository mocks;
        private ITransaction mockITransaction;
        public stubBaseTx()
        {
            mocks = new Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository();
            mockITransaction = mocks.DynamicMock<ITransaction>();
            mocks.ReplayAll();
        }
        protected override ITransaction FlowProperty_Transaction
        {
            get
            {
                return mockITransaction;
            }
        }
    }
   public class StubWithdrFlowISONet :WithdrawalFlowISONet
    {
       private MockRepository mocks;


        private bool FlowProperty_PINReAv = false;
        public StubWithdrFlowISONet()
        {
            mocks = new Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository();

            mocks.ReplayAll();
            stubBaseTx obj = new stubBaseTx();

            base.CreateCRMManager();

        }

        protected override bool FlowProperty_PINRetriesAvailable
        {
            get
            {

                return FlowProperty_PINReAv;
            }
        }


    }
```

Here WithdrawalFlowISONet is inhereted from WithdrawalFlowOperation class and WithdrawalFlowOperation  is inhereted from BaseTxFlowOperations class , now i have FlowProperty_Transaction
property in BaseTxFlowOperations which i have to pass to WithdrawalFlowISONet class but it  is readonly which can be modified in BaseTxFlowOperations only now i have created stubBaseTx class just to modify FlowProperty_Transaction
property , so how can i assign stubBaseTx class to WithdrawalFlowISONet class so that it should work as a base for WithdrawalFlowISONet class.
[C#]
Thanks,
Nishant